# Send request not showing in rest client

Tags: vscode-extensions, rest-client

I have installed rest client extension in VScode, but when I create .rest file and make some requests I don’t see the send request link

```
### 
GET http://localhost:3000/signin
```

Comment: This question is confusing.  If you say that the send request link didn't exist then how did you make the requests?  Did you mean you are trying to make requests unsuccessfully because there is no send button appearing?  Is that one line you have posted the only line in your .rest file?

Answer (score 0):

You can add three # symbol after each request like below:

POST http://localhost:8800/api/carts/
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{
"productId": "63c00763e65ebde449e9b411",
"quantity": "1"
}

3 '###' here

GET http://localhost:8800/api/carts/

Comment: That doesn't answer the question at all which had nothing to do with putting multiple requests into a file.

Answer (score 0):

You can view the request details by opening the request history and selecting the first entry.

Press Ctrl + Alt + H to open the request history (or run 'Rest Client: View  Request History' from the command palette).

Reference: https://github.com/Huachao/vscode-restclient#request-history

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this what you are looking for, but if you would like to see your request displayed in the same window as response, you need to add the following configuration to your settings.json file:

```
    "rest-client.previewOption":"exchange"
```

This is covered in "Customize Response Preview" section of the [help page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=humao.rest-client)